# Check for equality between more than 2 values in Lua

Tags: lua

In Lua 5.3.3, equalities between two values work normally using the `==` operator.

However, equalities between more than two values don't work.

```lua
> print(1 == 1 == 1)
false
>
```

How can I check if more than 2 values are equal to one another in Lua?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compare 2 values at a time:

```
print((1 == 1) and (1 == 1))
```

If you have specific needs and if this approach is not acceptable, then you could also write a dedicated function:

```
function EqualsAll (Values, Number)
  local Equals = true
  local Index  = 1

  while (Equals and (Index <= #Values)) do
    if Values[Index] == Number then
      Index = Index + 1
    else
      Equals = false
    end
  end

  return Equals
end
```

You could use it as following:

```
> EqualsAll({1, 2, 3}, 1)
false
> EqualsAll({1, 1, 1}, 1)
true
```